# Scala get page content as JSon

Tags: json, scala

I want to get the content of a page as JSON.

For now, I am doing this:

```
val content = new Scanner(url.openStream).useDelimiter("\\Z").next()
val rawJson = JParser.parseFromString(content).get
```

However, I'm having some issues because the method `useDelimiter("\\Z")` ruins the format of the text. But otherwise I don't know how to get the entire content of the scanner.

Is there a better of getting the JSON content from a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries available for doing this, for simple tasks I've been using a lot [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) with success.

A simple usage would be:

```
val rawJson = Http("http://localhost:8080/hello").asString.body
```

The documentation has lots of other examples you can look at.

Answer (score 3):

`scala.io.Source` provides built-in support for getting the body of an HTTP response, with no extra libraries:

```
import scala.io.Source.fromURL
val json = fromURL("http://localhost:8080/hello").mkString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Source.fromURL(url).mkString
```

works fine if you don't need to mess with the encoding. Of course, you probably want to wrap it in a Future...